# Reload frame after selecting option in another frame

Tags: javascript, html

I have PHP page in subfolder, /subfolder.
In root I have two files: index.html and demo.html.

demo.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-frameset.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf8" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
    <!--
    function MM_jumpMenu(targ,selObj,restore){ //v3.0
        eval(targ+".location='"+selObj.options[selObj.selectedIndex].value+"'");
        if (restore) selObj.selectedIndex=0;
    }
    //-->
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="demo_wrapper">
        <div id="themeslist">
            <form action="" name="form" id="form">
                <select name="select" onChange="MM_jumpMenu('parent',this,1)">
                    <option value="#">Select Theme</option>
                    <option value="http://127.0.0.1/themes/index.php?theme=1">Theme1</option>
                    <option value="http://127.0.0.1/themes/index.php?theme=3">Theme2</option>
                </select>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-frameset.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf8" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
</head>
    <frameset rows="100,*" framespacing="0" frameborder="no" border="0">
        <frame src="http://127.0.0.1/demo.html" name="head_frame" scrolling="no" noresize="noresize" id="head_frame" title="head_frame" />
        <frame src="http://127.0.0.1/themes/index.php" name="main_iframe" id="main_iframe" title="main_iframe" />
    </frameset>
<noframes>
<p>Your browser does not handle frames!</p>
</noframes>
</html>
```

Source: http://www.entheosweb.com/website_design/jump_menus.asp

Now problem is when i select option in menu - it reloads whole page and frames dissapear.
What change to reload only selected frame (main_iframe)?

Comment: you should set 'id' for frames and change 'parent' to top.document.getElementById('__frame_id'). And in MM_jumpMenu() you should change eval(targ+".location='"+selObj.options[selObj.selectedIndex].value+"'") to targ.src=selObj.options[selObj.selectedIndex].value;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found solution:

It was way too easy... just changed onchange action in select menu to:

```
onchange="window.open(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value, 'nameOfTargetFrame')"
```

and removed whole *MM_jumpMenu* code. Thanks for tips, I wouldn't found it without them :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you don't use iframe, you use the old fasion frameset. However,

In your form that handles the select menu, you have to set target attribute to be the name of the frame you wants the location open in it, as follows:

```
<form action="" name="form" id="form" target="main_iframe">
```

You have to choose the target to be suitable with the window name that you want to open it. i.e main_iframe or anything else.